# How to send inline table as parameter to function that receives a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to use *returning_tbl()*, from the code below, inside a WITH clause and then pass the inline table created with the WITH clause, as a parameter to a function. Like in *using_tbl_v2* (does not work at this time)

*using_tbl_v1* is just an example of things that work (but they are to simple for me).

And I realized that, once I create an inline table, I am exiting PLSQL mode and going into SQL mode. But how do I go back inside PLSQL mode to deliver *original_tbl* to *receiving_tbl( ... )*

```
create or replace type SOME_OBJ force as object (
  SOME_VARCHAR varchar2(20 byte)
);

create or replace type SOME_TBL is table of SOME_OBJ;


create or replace function returning_tbl
  return SOME_TBL pipelined is

begin
  for current_row in (
    select
      'SOME_VALUE' as SOME_VARCHAR
    from dual
  )
  loop
    pipe row (
      SOME_OBJ(
        current_row.SOME_VARCHAR
      )
    );
  end loop;
  return;
END returning_tbl;

select * from table(returning_tbl());


create or replace function receiving_tbl(tbl SOME_TBL)
  return SOME_TBL pipelined is

begin
  for current_row in (
    with filtered_tbl as (
      select
        SOME_VARCHAR
      from table(tbl)
      where SOME_VARCHAR = 'SOME_VALUE'
    )
    select * from filtered_tbl
  )
  loop
    pipe row (
      SOME_OBJ(
        current_row.SOME_VARCHAR
      )
    );
  end loop;
  return;
END receiving_tbl;


select * from table(receiving_tbl(returning_tbl()));


create or replace function using_tbl_v1
  return SOME_TBL pipelined is

begin
  for current_row in (
    with original_tbl as (
      select
        SOME_VARCHAR
      from table(returning_tbl())
      where SOME_VARCHAR = 'SOME_VALUE'
    ),
    outside_inlined_tbl as ( --just as example
      select * from table(receiving_tbl(returning_tbl()))
    )
    select * from outside_inlined_tbl
  )
  loop
    pipe row (
      SOME_OBJ(
        current_row.SOME_VARCHAR
      )
    );
  end loop;
  return;
END using_tbl_v1;


select * from table(using_tbl_v1());


create or replace function using_tbl_v2
  return SOME_TBL pipelined is

begin

  for current_row in (
    with original_tbl as (
      select
        SOME_VARCHAR
      from table(returning_tbl())
      where SOME_VARCHAR = 'SOME_VALUE'
    ),
    outside_tbl as (
      select * from table(receiving_tbl( original_tbl ))
    )
    select * from outside_tbl
  )
  loop
    pipe row (
      SOME_OBJ(
        current_row.SOME_VARCHAR
      )
    );
  end loop;
  return;
END using_tbl_v2;


select * from table(using_tbl(_v2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
with original_tbl as (
  select
    SOME_VARCHAR
  from table(returning_tbl())
  where SOME_VARCHAR = 'SOME_VALUE'
),
outside_tbl as (
  select * from table(receiving_tbl( original_tbl
  ))
)
select * from outside_tbl
```

With:

```
with original_tbl as (
  select
    SOME_VARCHAR
  from table(returning_tbl())
  where SOME_VARCHAR = 'SOME_VALUE'
),
outside_tbl as (
  select * from table(receiving_tbl(
     (select cast(collect(SOME_OBJ(SOME_VARCHAR)) as SOME_TBL) from original_tbl)
  ))
)
select * from outside_tbl
```

I'd like to add some simple explanation of what's happening here.  But this example is so complicated I'm not sure if there's any easy lesson to learn here.